# RAID5 FOREIGN DRIVE ISSUE

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I have Dell PowerEdge R620 Server on which Vmware Esxi host is running but yesterday 2 HDD showing missing and foreign state.

**[Dell powerEdge R620 Foreign configuration found on adapter. Press any key continue or "c" load the configuration utility or "f" to import foreign configuration and continue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSs5y.png)**

Please suggest what step will save my Raid 5 without loosing data

Comment: Cool story, bro. Id there a question here?

Comment: `Please suggest what step will save my Raid 5 without loosing data` With two dead drives in a RAID5, I'd hope my backup is up to date because more likely then not, that array is gone for good. When you restore, switch to a better RAID type. If you have no good backup, hire a data recover company ...

Comment: Should i press the "F" aur "C"

Comment: Try 'C' and 'V' :)

Comment: please suggest clearly what i need to do to start my server again

Comment: Restore from backup. RAID is not for preserving data, it's for maintaining availability.

Comment: By the way: RAID5 is a terrible, horrible, no good, very bad RAID. If you're looking for sensible defaults, choose RAID6 if you want cheap and slow across many drives, or RAID1+0 if you want fast but not cheap. If you had been using RAID6 or RAID1+0 this error would not have taken down your array.

Comment: can i power off the server and replace these 2 faulty HDD with new one and then start ? after that i think it will start rebuilding right ?

Comment: @RohitSingh: No, it won't. RAID5 can withstand the failure of a single disk. If two disks fail, your data is lost except you either have a good backup or spend a lot of money for a professional data recovery service (the second option is not guaranteed, they can't do magic).

Answer (score 4):

> "Please suggest what step will save my Raid 5 without loosing data"

Restore from last known good backup, oh and don't use RAID5.

Comment: +1 for "don't use RAID5"